# R: Doing t-test between pairs of factors

Tags: r

I have an R data frame with a factor variable with 8 levels (ordered). I want to do a t-test between level 1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6 and 7 & 8. While I can subset the data to extract each pair of categories, I am wondering if there is a easier way to do it. Can't figure out. Tried the following, but it complains about differing lengths (each level has different number of observations):

```
t.test(var1 ~ levels(factorvar)[1:2], data = mydf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is probably because `levels(factorvar)[1:2]` returns just two values "1" and "2", but `t.test` expects the length of the vectors on both sides of the `~` to be the same. In other words, it's not an issue of having different numbers of observations in each factor level. Rather, if, for example, you have 40 values of `var1` for `factorvar`=1 and 50 values of `var1` for `factorvar`=2, then you need a vector of length 90 on both sides of the `~`.

Try this instead:

```
t.test(var1 ~ factorvar, data=mydf[mydf$factorvar %in% c(1,2),])
```

You can also create a function so that you don't have to type all that code for each combination of factors:

```
# Function to return p-values from t-test between two factor levels
my.t = function(fac1, fac2){
  t.test(mydf$var1[mydf$factorvar==fac1], 
         mydf$var1[mydf$factorvar==fac2])$p.value
}

# Run the function on factor levels 1 and 2
my.t(1,2)

# Do all four at once
mapply(my.t, seq(1,7,2), seq(2,8,2))
```

If you want to return the entire output of the t-test for each pair of factor levels (rather than just the p-values), then remove the `$p.value` from the function above and run `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` added.

This is a coding site, rather than a statistical advice site, but also beware of [multiple comparisons](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/posthoc.htm).

Answer (score 2):

```
pairs <- list( c(1, 2), c(3, 4), c(5, 6), c(7, 8) )
lapply(pairs, function(pr) {
       t.test( var1 ~ factorvar, 
               data=dat[dat$factorvar %in$ pr, c("var1", "factorvar")] )
                          }
       )
```

I don't the the extra (unrepresented) levels should cause problems with `t.test.formula` since the factors would get coerced to mumeric. Could also try:

```
lapply(pairs, function(pr) {
         t.test( var1 ~ factorvar, 
                 data=dat[ , c("var1", "factorvar")],
                 subset= factorvar %in% pr)
                          } )
```

Note: Tested with:

```
dat <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(100), 
                  factorvar=factor(sample(1:8, 100, rep=TRUE)))
```

Sample output:

```
[[1]]

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  var1 by factorvar
t = -1.2077, df = 8.419, p-value = 0.26
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.3597432  0.4197142
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
     -0.1819342       0.2880802 


[[2]]

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  var1 by factorvar
t = -0.8141, df = 20.676, p-value = 0.4249
#--------- rest of output snipped-------
```