# R Beginner: Loops on a Welch t-test

Tags: r, for-loop

I am just starting to pick up R to help with a new retailing project, and although I can punch in some basic functions, I am looking for a way to do some sales comparisons more efficiently. The following is a condensed example.

I would like to compare the means for total purchases by six different types of customers (noted using the factor MemberType with 6 levels, one for each type of rewards membership enrollment).

Although I can certainly do something like this:

```
>m<-t.test(TotalPurchase[MemberType=='2'],TotalPurchase[MemberType=='4'])
```

for each pair, my objective here is to avoid running the test for each pair of factor levels manually.

At this early stage I do not understand conceptually how to go about this. Is it possible to use the function across a vector of unique factor levels, e.g.

```
>tp<-data.frame(levels(MemberType))
```

? If so, are there any insights on how/whether to construct a nested for-loop something like

```
>for(i in tp) function(i){
>##something like tt<-t.test(TotalPurchase[MemberType==i],##
>##+t.test(TotalPurchase[MemberType==i])##
>+}
```

with an additional layer? I have also monkeyed around with the 'apply' family of functions but am stumped by 1)the need for two inputs into the two-sample t.test
and by 2)the indexing syntax in the for() and lapply() arguments that tell R what vector of values to use in the t-test.

Any specific help on this problem or polite guidance on my formatting in R (or in Stack Overflow) will be greatly appreciated by this novice. Thanks!

Comment: Do either of the answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930881/r-doing-t-test-between-pairs-of-factors/27931772#27931772) solve your problem?

Comment: Looks promising...I will try it out at the office tomorrow and update accordingly. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: In general, for problems like this, you can use one of the `apply` family of functions (`apply`, `lapply`, etc.) rather than loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way is to use `pairwise.t.test()` in the `stats` package.

- But you need to be clear on what type of multiple-test adjustment
  you'd like to use to control your family wise error rate. So, it's
  really a statistics question and not a programming question. Do you
  have a preference between Bonferroni or others?
- You're also unclear on the if you're using pooled variance or not.
- Finally, your data is unclear.

If you have a data frame with the variables: `purchases` is the measurement variable, `MemberType` for customer category, and `ItemType` as the item category, and you want Bonferroni corrections and unpooled SD, this will work for the example item type == a:

```
df <- data.frame(purchases= rnorm(100, 50, 20), 
      MemberType= factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 100, replace= TRUE)),
      ItemType= factor(sample(c("d","e","f"), 100, replace=TRUE))
df2 <- df[df$ItemType == "a", ]
pairwise.t.test(df2$purchases, df2$MemberType, p.adj= "bonf", pool.sd= FALSE)
```

Please provide a complete description of your problem and I can update this solution as needed.

Comment: Please bear with me as I work through these responses today to provide updates. Thanks for your help thus far! Please note that I have corrected a misleading typo in my description: I am not examining ItemType at all right now, and currently only wish to compare factor levels on MemberType. I apologize for the oversight.

Comment: I *believe* I have what I was looking for using

Comment: I *believe* I have what I was looking for using <br/>    ##df entry and organization omitted##<br/>    >pairwise.t.test(TotalPurchase,MemberType,p.adj="bonf",pool.sd=FALSE)<br/> I am just now trying to learn some stats again after years away from school and need to do some homework to ensure that I am using the correct arguments in the pairwise.t.test function (links to other sx discussions on choosing pooled variance and adjustments would be greatly helpful if you have any). Thanks @eipi10 and Alex for your assistance!